# May "offset" in poisson regression be a constant?

Tags: poisson-regression, offset

Let's say I'm trying to model the incidence of disease per 1000 people.
I have data where people are id'd for example 1001,1002,1003,....

am I allowed to specify the offset as

`geeglm(y~offset(log(1000))+x_1+x_2+...x_n,family=poisson,id=id,corstr=...)`?

In other words, can the offset in poisson regression be a constant not in the dataframe?

Comment: What difference do you see between what you suggest and what the documentation says? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/offset They look the same to me, and it will help people answer if you can clarify the difference.

Comment: Im suggesting a number while the documentation suggests an object. r treats everything as a vector and numbers are vectors therefore what I’m suggesting will work

Comment: Does your code not compile and give a model with log (1000) as the intercept?

Comment: No I was asking a hypothetical question

Comment: It seems like you are asking an R question, rather than a statistics one. Questions about programming are off-topic here. But if you can reframe your question to emphasize the statistics part (if that is what you are asking about) it will be on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `geeglm()` uses the standard R formula-processing machinery (`model.matrix()` and related), the offset doesn't need to be in the data frame, but it *does* need to be the same length as the other variables: R does not automatically recycle/replicate the offset as it does in most other contexts.

```
geeglm(y~offset(rep(log(1000),nrow(dd)))+x1+ ...,
       data=dd, ...)
```

For this reason it may be simpler (although a tiny bit wasteful) to add it to the data frame, where it will automatically be replicated appropriately:

```
dd$off <- log(1000)
geeglm(y ~ offset(off) + x_1 + ..., data=dd, ...)
```